# RPG with background in ancient Europe (-1000 to 1000) close to reality

Tags: game-recommendation, historical-settings

I want to run a game which as both an historical and geographical background matching our own reality. 
Description of lore should be quite accurate, but can have a pinch of myth, legend and magic as perceived in the ancient time (oracle, healer, tribe's shaman, witches, healing plants, deities, ...). However monsters and powerful wizards should be only present in oral traditions.

The goal is to run a game that can help to acquire knowledge about ancient time while having the fun of roleplaying.

Comment: Did you even look? Wikipeadi has [a list of historical RPGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_role-playing_games_by_genre#Historical.2Fperiod_adventure) and [a category dedicated to it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Historical_role-playing_games).  Why are those not enough?  What are you really looking for?

Comment: Well wikipedia is not always uptodate and does not provide any gamer feedback. I'm looking for feedback and advices from gamers.

Comment: System recommendation questions must be tightly scoped to be allowed on RPG.SE; see our [System Recommendation Q&A Guidance](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic) for more. Closely define what you need and then answers must follow ["Good Subjective, Bad Subjective"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) criteria and only recommend what they have experience in and not just toss out Googled lists.  In this case you haven't narrowed this down enough - there are hundreds of games that are historically based.

Comment: Closed for a while to give you a chance to edit the question and make it more specific where it might have a best answer.

Comment: How can I improve such a question ? I don't want a complete list of historical rpg. I want feedback for player or gm about their own experiences. I don't know how to narrow the scope except by splitting the question into many sub-questions.

Comment: What's wrong in my question compared to this one, given as a model in the FAQ ? http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9691/what-role-playing-games-best-emulate-a-non-mystical-old-west-setting

Comment: I totally overhaul the question, but I can not pick a period. Or I can ask 10 times the same questions, shifting the period on each, but this is non-sense. The focus is more on the learning accurate historical stuff than playing in 9th century in Londinium during Viking invasion...

Comment: Ask yourself what would make a "best" answer.  Is it most accurate historical accuracy?  Is it volume of historical material in the actual game books?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not trying to solve a problem... Is that a restriction on rpgSE ? Both Rome and Iceland answer are great.

Comment: @Guillaume Yes, that's a restriction of all Stacks. The platform only works well when the questions have concrete problems and answers. RPG.SE is not a replacement for [forums](http://rpg.net) and discussion-type questions that would be at home on a forum are out of place here. You'll likely get much better discussion and exploration of the field of historical RPGs at a forum anyway—the format here just doesn't support that like a forum does. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3):

[Rome: Life and Death of the Republic](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/50481/rome-life-and-death-of-the-republic) is very historically accurate. I found it useful for a Roman-style game I ran earlier this year (although I added in some details from the history series *[In Our Time](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/iot)* and mythology).

Answer (score 1):

[Mythic Iceland](http://catalog.chaosium.com/product_info.php?products_id=6689) is written to support gamers looking for a purely historical Viking-Age setting, as well as a mythical Viking World that includes rune magic and creatures from Nordic mythology and Icelandic fairy-tales.